# why is disabled <select> included in form submission?

Tags: html, forms, http

I have a form that includes this disabled field

```
<select disabled="disabled" name="organization.id" class="userInputField">
  <option value="2">organization</option>
</select>
```

When I submit the form to the server (as a regular HTTP POST, rather than AJAX), this field *is* included in the request params, but I thought disabled fields were supposed to be excluded?

### Please Ignore & Close

My mistake - some rogue JavaScript was removing the disabled attribute before the form is submitted. Thanks for your help, and sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: I copied that code into a form with a submit button. The field was **not** included in the submitted data.

Comment: Ditto here. What browser?

Comment: @YuriyGalanter Firefox 28.0

Comment: @Don nope, not happening. Are u sure nothing on the client removes the attribute prior to submission?

Answer (score 3):

Your select is **not** included in the post when disabled. I used the following minimal page as a test under Firefox and only saw non-disabled fields. Firebug output of the form submit is shown below

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="test.html">
<input type="text" name="test1" disabled>
<select  name="organization.id" class="userInputField" disabled="disabled">
   <option  selected value="2">organization</option>
</select>
<button name="submitbutton" type="submit">Test</button>
</form>
</html>
```

[image: Submit in Firebug]

I suggest you check if you did any of the following:

- misread the details
- got your HTML nesting wrong
- giving two fields the same name
- accidentally declaring a variable of the same name in the form processing script.

I also suggest you put a more complete example online.